# subprocess won't start other py script

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use subprocess.run() to start several other instances of a py script in a 'fire and forget' way and I can't get it to work. It does not generate any errors, but the process.py never starts (pleased see code below). I am clueless as to what is happening and what else to try... Thanks!

The command I'm trying to execute is: 
(example): `python "S:\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py" --p_id 4 --rerun_override 1`

This is how I'm trying to execute the command above, and it does not work:

```
subprocess.run([r'''python''', r'''"S:\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py" --p_id ''' + str(this_p_id) + ''' --rerun_override 1 ''' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

If I run that same command from a command prompt (this is happening on a windows server, Python 3.7) it runs fine.

If put in a batch file in the same directory (S is a mapped drive), it runs fine:

```
subprocess.run([r'''S:\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\testrun.bat ''' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

I added a PAUSE to the batch file hoping to see something (keep the window open) but I didn't see anything.. (since it ran ok.)

Comment: Please format your question in a way that it is easily readable.

Comment: How do you know that the process is not started?

Comment: What happens if you use `subprocess.run(['python', r'S:\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py', '--p_id', this_p_id, '--rerun_override', 1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)`?

Comment: I know if process.py runs because it logs to both a file and a SQL table.

Comment: Here's what happens when I run it as you suggested: File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable.

Comment: changing this_p_id to str(this_p_id) doesn't make a difference, the error is the same.

Comment: There is no doubt that 'python "S:\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py" --p_id 4 --rerun_override 1' works. It works in cmd line or started by subprocess.run() in a batch file.

Comment: I just changed the code to:  result = subprocess.run…….. print(result.stdout)
    print(result.stderr) and now I am getting an error, it looks like it can't get to the file. (can\'t open file \'"\\\\…...\\S\\Python Scripts\\MasterProcess\\process.py" --p_id 1 --rerun_override 1 \': [Errno 22] Invalid argument\n'). Looks like I have a problem with double \\

Comment: If you needed to do `str(this_p_id)` then you also need to change `1` to `'1'`.

Comment: 1 is passed as a string, no need for that (' --rerun_override 1'). Interestingly, none of the usual ways to fix paths in windows works. No r', or \\. I've also eliminated the : in the path.. nothing works

Comment: Since doubling the escape characters does not work, I'm guessing this is because I have to use quotes within quotes (' ") or (''' ")

Comment: mkrieger1, you were right about that, but I also needed commas between args, in other words pass it a list not just with the executable and the command as elements, but all args have to be elements as well: 'python', r"\\<servername>\S\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py", "--p_id", str(this_p_id), "--rerun_override", "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments must be passed as a list, not a string, correct syntax is:
'python', r"\\S\Python Scripts\MasterProcess\process.py", "--p_id", str(this_p_id), "--rerun_override", "1"